# Why I can't make a insert in Postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am using Postgresql whith Django but I have a problem when I try to make a INSERTO INTO in PgAdmin 4 always show this message:

```
Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.
```

But in other database I can do a Insert, I don't understand why in the database created by Djando I can't make a query, I have reinstall postgresql but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does postgresql says anything in the logs?

Comment: May be the credentials with which you have connected to the PgAdmin  different than the credentials used Django setting.py for database.

Comment: I check the logs and I find the error the problem is that I did a bad query.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are actually connected to PostgreSQL server before executing query in PgAdmin.

Also make sure you created database as Django doesn't do it on it own ( it creates only tables inside configured database

What other databases you are referring to please elaborate?